# Robotframework or Jenkins run process flask and perform the robotframework tests on it

Tags: python, selenium, flask, jenkins, robotframework

I just started with the robotframework and seleniumlibrary so i dont know if what i want to do is possible.

The setup:
I have a website as a flask service that is run on a server, i have a SVN versioning and a Jenkins with robotframework setup to test one branch from SVN.

So i DO NOT want to test the released live website, i want to test the trunk (Development branch) before i tag it and make a new release published.

This means that i do not have the site i want to test live on a server, i run it locally as i develop on it.
All test work if i start the flask app on localhost and run the test i have, but now i want to run them in jenkins instead without me having to start the flask app manually.

This is the flow i want to accieve if possible:

```
 * Jenkins get informed of new version of trunk from SVN Hook
 * Jenkins or robotframework prepares for the tests by starting the main.py flask app that the test should be run on
 * Jenkins run the RobotFramework tests from the robot file that does testing against http://localhost:5005 (This is the config of the flask app that probably should be something else when started from robotframework or jenkings?)
 * The tests is done and a report is made and the results published
 * In the future automatically tag and release the site if the test is approved
```

This is the config of the flask app if run without a config (Port is 5005 in default config)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = config['MonitorAndConfigure']['port']
    app.run(debug=True, port=port, host='0.0.0.0')
```

With this flow i can publish my site and know it's working.

so the problem i have is the part where jenkins or robotframework should start the flask app and then close it again when the test is complete.

I have tried starting the flask app as a process in robotframework but it seems like it gets a temp path and port so the tests fail

```
Library                        Process

Suite Setup                    Start Process    python    ../main.py
...                            Wait for process

Suite Teardown                 Terminate All Processes
```

This is the first test:

```
*** Variables ***
${URL}          http://localhost:5005
${BROWSER}      headlesschrome

*** Test Cases ***
User can open the home page
    [Documentation]             As a user i can open the home page and see the site

    open browser                ${URL}    ${BROWSER}
    Wait Until Page Contains    Systems Learch
    Close Browser
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by running it as a shell buildstep and starting flask as a background service:

```
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
export DISPLAY=:1
python3 main.py config_jenkins.json &
sleep 10
robot -d tests/results tests/test_website.robot
```

The `python3 main.py config_jenkins.json &` runs the flask service as a background service during the test, the sleep was needed to give flask some time to start and publish the site.

For the robot framework to work with chrome inside jenkins i needed to make a dummy display with xvfb:

```
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
export DISPLAY=:1
```

The chromedriver is installed inside the jenkins docker image and added to PATH.
I also had to change the owner of google chrome to jenkins from root in the container so jenkins could start chrome without problems.